# Mockito.spy executing different code base

Tags: mockito

I am using the following mockito .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I have class

```
public class Test(){
  private String config;
  public getConfig()
 {
   return config;
 }

  public String test(){
   return getConfig();
  }
}
```

The test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass(){

@Test
public void mockTest()
{
Test test = Mockito.spy(Test.class);
Mockito.when(test.getConfig()).thenReturn("test");
String result = test.test();
assertEquals("test",result);
}
```

However the mock is not working. The code base also is different while debugging. Some lines get skipped . Can anyone help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using of Mockito.spy, you should pass existing (created) object, like `new Test()` in you case.

Example:

```
public class Spy {
    private String config = "real";

    public String getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public String test() {
        return getConfig();
    }
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
public void mockTest() {
    Spy test = Mockito.spy(new Spy());
    Mockito.when(test.getConfig()).thenReturn("test");

    String result = test.test();

    assertEquals("test", result);
}
```

Comment: yes mocking working , thank you . I am still facing issue where some lines get skipped while debugging . Cursor at line , but actual execution is different. I am saying on basis on logs. While I am executing a one line , some other logic is getting executing.

Comment: @ysn I can't understand what exactly you mean. Could you post some code you are working with? And the steps you take.
Also to understand how Mockito Spy objects works you could read here:  https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.7.7/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13